# What's the name for the property of a function $f$ that means $f(f(x))=x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, definition

I can think of several examples of functions such that twice application of the function is equivalent to no application of it.

- Additive inverse
- Multiplicative inverse
- Fourier transform
- Complex conjugation
- Any group built up from $\mathbb{Z}_2$, applying (one of) the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ parts' operation.

"Idempotent" came to mind, but that's wrong. It means $f(f(x)) = f(x)$, not $f(f(x))=x$.

What is the word for this "flip-flop" property?

Comment: [Involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))

Comment: also known as '$f$ is its own inverse'

Comment: @BrandonCarter Why did you comment instead of answering? I'm not sure whether to "award" the checkmark to you or Leandro.

Comment: Fourier transform doesn't have that property ;) You get an extra reflection....

Comment: @N.S. Can you explain that? I thought F.T. is its own inverse.

Comment: @LaoTzu Is not, it is "almost" it's own inverse. $\widehat{\widehat{f}}(x)=f(-x)$.... Keep in mind that for characters $-\chi$ is the same thing as complex conjugation, that's why usually this is written as "the inverse Fourier Transform has an exta conjugate"...

Comment: Relatedly, you have involutory matrices, matrices that are the "square roots" of the identity matrix.

Comment: @LaoTzu I don't feel that I deserve reputation for a one word response; commenting is quicker than making an answer community wiki.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functions that are their own inversion.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356095/functions-that-are-their-own-inversion)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: You do realize that this question was asked in 2011 and the one that you consider to be the original was asked in 2015, do you? Which one do you think is the original and which one the duplicate, then?

Comment: @AlexM. It's irrelevant. I took in consideration the quality of the questions and most importantly their answers into account.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: While your argument has its merit, it amounts to redefining the word "duplicate". I suggest that we use it in the precise sense that it has in any dictionary and conserve our originality for more significant tasks.

Comment: @AlexM. You're the one being pedant about definitions. The time two questions were asked is irrelevant when considering which to close as a duplicate of the other. Only the usefulness of both is. Why do you think it's possible to close an older question as a duplicate of a newer one? It's not an oversight. If you're unhappy, open a meta thread.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is called an "Involution".

Answer (score 26):

[Involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) is the most common name. They are so fundamental that an entire book has been written on them, the [Book of Involutions.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809040) I often emphasize their essential role both [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+involution) and [various](http://groups.google.com/groups/search?hl=en&q=group%3A*math*+author%3Adubuque+involutions) other [places.](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fat.yorku.ca%2Fcgi-bin%2Fbbqa+dubuque+involution&pbx=1&oq=site:http%3A%2F%2Fat.yorku.ca%2Fcgi-bin%2Fbbqa+dubuque+involution&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2418l10983l0l11466l59l31l0l0l0l6l265l3301l18.11.2l31l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=7a815af5c44e7640&biw=1394&bih=1422) One should always strive to bring to the fore the innate symmetries in problems, and involutions are  one of the simplest examples.

Note: you could have found the answer simply by Googling "self inverse function". The first match is the "self inverse" section of the Wikipedia page on inverse functions, which states "such a function is called an involution".

Comment: Self inverse. I didn't think of that. I googled for something approximately like the title. (the word _self inverse_ didn't come readily to mind because I was thinking $f^2=f^0$ rather than $f^1 = f^{-1}$)

Comment: @Lao It is well-worth the effort to learn how to compose effective searches, by means of which you can truly **stand on the shoulder of giants** - exposing many beautiful mathematical vistas.